# Merging the columns based on findingthe closest date in range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe having multiple columns and another bigger dataframe with other multiple columns.

The matching columns in df1 are symbol,m_date
the matching columns in df2 are symbol, date

I want to get the values for other columns from df2 to df1 such that

```
if m_date = date matches for a particular symbol, then copy the other columns 
if m_date != date for a particular symbol, then we find the closest date to m_date in df2 and use their values to be added to the df1
```

I tried

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=df31, right=df2, how='left', left_on=['symbol','m_date'], right_on=['symbol','date'])
```

This merges the file, but the dates that are not available have corresponding values as blank. Can anyone advise as to how to achieve the same

Thanks

Comment: this could be possible with [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), but without a couple of rows that could match from both dataframes, it is difficult to answer for sure. Please add some input data

Comment: @Ben.T I created a dummy dataframe to share. Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MwXMDZ8hSLQcv1qBy4cpDszmsWm-lcSaYh6nUGUwWNM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), you can use `by` to merge on symbol first and then `on` the column date to find the `nearest`. The date needs to be datetime and sorted.

```
# some data similar to yours but simplified
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A'},
                     'var1': {0: 34, 1: 45, 2: 43, 3: 67},
                     'm_date': {0: '11/25/19', 1: '8/14/19', 2: '5/14/19', 3: '2/20/19'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A'},
                    'date': {0: '1/2/19', 1: '5/3/19', 2: '8/4/19', 3: '1/5/20', 4: '1/8/20'},
                    'Per1d': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 8, 4: 6},})

# create a column with the dates as datetime
df1['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['m_date'])
df2['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

# merge_asof
df3 = (pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('date_'), 
                     df2.sort_values('date_'), 
                     by=['symbol'], on=['date_'], 
                     direction='nearest')
      )
print (df3)
  symbol  var1    m_date      date_    date  Per1d
0      A    67   2/20/19 2019-02-20  1/2/19      1
1      A    43   5/14/19 2019-05-14  5/3/19      3
2      A    45   8/14/19 2019-08-14  8/4/19      5
3      A    34  11/25/19 2019-11-25  1/5/20      8
```

Comment: I am getting unexpected EOF with the code that you shared.

Comment: @vp7 I just copied and paste the code and I don't get this error, did you copy the last closing parenthesis the line before the `print`, it is necessary

Comment: This works, but I have a question, since it would pick the nearest one, I dont' want it to pick the date ahead of it.. in allthe cases date chosen should be below m_date. what direction should we place then

Comment: @vp7 direction can be 'forward' and 'backward' instead of 'nearest', if I understand your comment, I would use backward, but maybe try with both and see which direction is the one you look for ;)